# Можно ли посмотреть что выполняется в фоновом процессе cmd.exe?

Tags: cmd, процесс

Windows 10.
Допустим, висит несколько процессов cmd.exe, можно ли мне вывести их из фонового режима и отобразить в терминале (или еще где-то) выполняемые инструкции.